# Play sound on mouse hover using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible play song on mouse hover using javascript?
If yes then how to code for it.

Comment: Why would you ever want to annoy users like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible. You need **javascript** for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with CSS.  You can, however, use JavaScript to trigger an audio element to play when any other element is moused over.

Answer (score 1):

If your audience is using screen readers it may be possible with aural style sheets:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/aural.html

```
blockquote.sad { play-during: url("violins.aiff") }
```